# Find highest possible number under certain time span?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, max

For Python 3, is there a possibility to find the highest possible calculated number in a function under a specific time span?
For example if something would take almost 'forever', is there a way to find out the highest possible number to be calculated under 1 minute?

Here is the code:

```
def fibonacci5(n):
f1, f2 = 1, 0               
while n > 0:
    f1, f2 = f1 + f2, f1     
    n -= 1
return f2
```

I am trying to use the possible solution for finding the number that takes 1 second via timeit.

```
repeats = 10
t = timeit.Timer("fibonacci5(500000)", globals=globals())
time = t.timeit(repeats)
print ("average execution time:", time/repeats)
```

But 500.000 takes on average 2,6s, while 250.000 takes on average 0,6s - so that solution can't work.

Comment: That would depend entirely on what the algorithm is. We need more context.

Comment: In this case, it is for calculating the Fibonacci number.

Comment: Well, the Fibonacci sequence is infinite afaik, so any Fibonacci function that's ever been written would need the ability to stop before the end of the sequence. Have you looked up implementations for a Fibonacci function?

Comment: And as for calculating ad much as you can in under a minute: once you understand how to stop the sequence, you can calculate how many iterations you can do in a second, multiply that by 60, and you have your limit. Or calculate how long each iteration takes, and divide 60 by that length of time.

Comment: I do have some implementations but none of them would stop the calculating until it's done. I know it's infinite, that's why I want to find out the maximum possible number before it reaches an execution time higher than 1 minute.

Comment: Read my third comment, and show what you have so far. This question is pretty broad as it currently stands, as answering it would require us to write a fairly large tutorial.

Comment: If you implement it as a generator function that yields intermediate values, you can iterate the function while checking how much time has elapsed. If you add the code of the function to your question, we can show you how if you don't understand.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 2):

you could add a timer to your function to make it stop after a given time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

max_runtime = timedelta(seconds=1)

def fibonacci5(n):

    stop_time = datetime.now() + max_runtime

    f1, f2 = 1, 0
    while n > 0:
        f1, f2 = f1 + f2, f1
        n -= 1
        if datetime.now() > stop_time:
            return f2, 'timelimit reached'
    return f2
```

note that if it returns when the time has run out that it will not just return a number, but a tuple with the number and the string `'timelimit reached'`. that way you can differentiate between normal termination and timeout (there may be better ways to handle that...).

the caveat here is that the `if` line (at least as long as your `int`s are still very small) is probably the line of the function that takes up the most amount of time... the results will therefore not represent the actual run-times very exactly...

also note that there are **way** more efficient ways to calculate fibonacci numbers.

Comment: That is quite useful to have a rough estimate of how far you can go before it takes too long. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if we write Fibonacci sequence generator like

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b
```

it looks naive but works fast enough, e.g. if you need `500000`th Fibonacci number we can use `itertools.islice`

```
from itertools import islice

fibonacci_500000 = next(islice(fibonacci(), 500000, 500001))
print(fibonacci_500000)
```

which took about 5 seconds on my old machine, output is too big to insert, but it looks like

```
47821988144175...more digits here...2756008390626
```

but if you really need to find out which value we've calculated after some time – we can use `timedelta` and `datetime` objects like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    duration = timedelta(seconds=5)
    fibonacci_numbers = fibonacci()
    stop = datetime.now() + duration
    for index, number in enumerate(fibonacci_numbers, start=1):
        if datetime.now() >= stop:
            break
    print(index)
```

which gives us `505352`th Fibonacci number calculated after approximately 5 seconds (we can also print `number`, but it is too long)

Comment: The thing is I don't need the number itself, I need to find out the maximum before the calculation takes too long :)